# ocaml 'a list list function tuples

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml

```
let sample_table4 = [
[["11"];["21"];["31"];["41"]];
[["12"];["22"];["32"]];
[["13"];["23"]];
[["14"]]];;
```

This is where I'm stuck with writing a function to get one of these numbers

```
let tgvc (pos, table) = 
match pos with
|[] -> []
|i::[j] -> List.nth (List.nth table (j-1)) (i-1)
|i::_ -> []
;;
val tgvc : int list * 'a list list list -> 'a list = <fun>
```

I'm supposed to get this signature

```
tgvc ([3;2],sample_table4);;
val tgvc : int list * ’a list list -> ’a = <fun>
-: string list = ["32"]
```

What's missing in the function?
I'm sure it has to be recursive now.
Even though it computes the right answer, it's not the right method. The ->[ ] is what's getting me

```
let rec tgvc (pos, table) = function
|_,[] -> []
|[i;1], h::_ -> List.nth h (i-1)
|[i;j], _::t -> tgvc ([i;j-1], t)
|_ -> []

|[i;j], _::t -> tgvc ([i;j-1], t)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Error: This expression has type int list * 'a list list list -> 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a list

Comment: please don't use tags unrelated to your question

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: it was just suggested by stack bc ocaml has low response

Comment: `let get_table_values_cell = fun [ i ; j ] table ->` I think this is the curry version but same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's missing in the function?

A lot of things. Your function simply returns one of many lists of initial input. You don't even use `i` indice.

I suggest you to think what your function need to do for the given input:

- `[i; 1], h::_` - you are "in front" of the desirable list
- `[i; j], _::t` - not desirable list yet (some recursion maybe?)
- `_, []` - empty table
- `_` - everything else

**Edit**

You have two problems with your last implementation. First of all in your first and last branches you return `[]`, I guess you would like to exit with an error, so you can throw an exception (via `failwith` for example). The second problem is actually in the first line: `get_table_values_cell (pos, table) = function`, it means that you define `get_table_values_cell` as function with two arguments, you give one explicitly (`(pos, table)`) and the second is introduced by `function` keyword. So all you need is to pick only one: `get_table_values_cell = function`

Comment: I had an updated answer but bc it was the wrong method it got deleted. I edited the wrong method into the original post, can you look again please